# works fine in local, but in production I get error saying violates foreign key constraint

Tags: python, django

The below is error message, I recently played around with my models.py and I get that. in local, every thing works as I expected but with elastic beanstalk I get the below error.

```
 [Instance: i-491802ee] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...l, params) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "main_category" violates foreign key constraint "main_categor_sponosred_id_1adc236d9d5dae5f_fk_main_sponsored_id" DETAIL: Key (sponosred_id)=(1) is not present in table "main_sponsored". container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/02_python.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Is this occuring because of elastic beanstalk?or something wrong with my code?

```
class Sponsored(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='sponsored1/', null=True, blank=True,max_length=255)


        objects = SponsoredManager()
class Category(models.Model): 

        sponsored = models.ForeignKey(Sponsored)
```

Edit:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0024_auto_20160328_2027'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='category',
            name='sponosred',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='main.Sponsored'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]


most recent one
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0029_category_sponsored'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='post',
            name='content',
            field=ckeditor_uploader.fields.RichTextUploadingField(),
        ),
    ]
```

I even tried adding this,

```
01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python ebagu/manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

in local everything works fine, because I put sponsored model before category model so there shouldn't be any problem. 
but when I run eb deploy I get the error....

Comment: Was `sponsored` added later? If so, did you set the default value for `sponsored` (non-null field without default value) in the `makemigrations` prompt to 1?

Comment: @kedar, yes i think so....do you mean add the following;01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python project/manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the migration file?

Comment: @kedar yeah certainly,,,,I have no idea why this has been killing me all morning

Comment: @kedar thanks for the help, I just editted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the migration:

```
field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='main.Sponsored'),
```

This means that existing rows of the `Category` table should use the value of 1 for the `sponsored` column (because it is non-null, every row must have this value).

It is failing in production as there is no row of the `Sponsored` table with the primary key of `1` (which is required as `sponsored` in `Category` is a foreign key)

Your local database has a row with primary key `1`, so it did not fail.

You can make the sponsored field nullable and run makemigrations & migrate again.

```
sponsored = models.ForeignKey(Sponsored, null=True)
```

Comment: yes I just tried it with null and blank = True but same thing happened... i deleted all my migration files and just ran eb deploy hopefully it works this time

Comment: Are you running `makemigrations` on production too? Ideally one would commit the results of `makemigrations` to source control, and only run `migrate` once on the production database.

Comment: hmm its taking some time, I deleted all my migration files and ran make and migrate but nothing got created....

Comment: oh i wasn't doing that till just now...I thought you meant I need to have that...my bad for misunderstanding

Comment: Deleting migration files will cause issues, as django keeps a record of the migrations that have been applied. If you re-create migrations and try to apply them again, it might fail as according to the migrations table, the new migrations haven't been applied, but the actual database structure has been modified already.

Comment: I re-create then with makemigrations and migrate right? oh ok I just checked my folder they have been re-created...

Comment: this time server works but I get (column main_category.sponsored_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ain_category"."hotCat", "main_category"."active", "main_cate...) when I go to my web...I deleted makemigrations and did eb deploy again...

Comment: `makemigrations` and `migrate` on local, and only `migrate` on production.

Comment: this is driving me crazy, eb deploy got finished and when I go to my web I get column "sponsored_id" of relation "main_category" does not exist, (I set debug=True for now)

Comment: even after I set it to null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107686/discussion-between-kedar-and-em-four).

Answer (score 0):

`violates foreign key constraint` error, raised by database.

Your `Category` model has a foreign key to `Sponsored` model.
If you try to insert an item into `Category` model while the referenced `Sponsored` object not exists,
database complains.

Solution:

1. Save `Sponsored` object before insert the corresponding item to `Category` model.
2. use `--natural-foreign` if you use django's `dumpdata` command
   `python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign`

Comment: yes I saved sponsored object before category model, I put class sponsored above class category, everything works perfectly in development...I don't understand why this is only happening when I do eb deploy(production)

Comment: @emfour It differs from databases, some can handle it by default. And, maybe there isn't such kind of initial data in your development. Or, the Sponsored items exist before migration. you can setup the system first, without initial data